# scrollイベントはいつ発火する？

Tags: javascript, dom

次のコードを実行してみて、スクロールバーを動かす速さによってコールバックが呼ばれる回数が異なることを知りました。（速ければ少なく、遅ければ多い）

```
window.onscroll = () => {
    console.log("scrolled");
};
```

スクロールイベントはどのような条件が揃うと発火するのでしょうか？

[scroll - Event reference | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll)などにも条件については書かれていないようです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

おおざっぱに言うと、暇なときにイベントが発火します。1つの要素に対して複数のイベントが溜まることはありません。

規格にのっとって説明すると([12.2. Scrolling](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#scrolling-events))、ブラウザがスクロール処理を行うとスクロールした要素が pending scroll event targets に溜められます。すでに要素が pending scroll event targets に入っている場合は何もしません。このため、どんなにたくさんスクロールしても、後述の処理が始まるまでは最大1つの `scroll`イベントしか予約されません。

[イベントループに入ったときに、run the scroll steps が起動](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loop-processing-model:run-the-scroll-steps)され、pending scroll event targets に対して `scroll` イベントを発火します。
ただし、scroll イベントハンドラはページを重くする要因となっていることが多いので、実際のブラウザではイベントループで毎回 run the scroll steps を起動していないかもしれません。

Answer (score 2):

## 実装依存

結論からいえば、実装依存ではないかと思います。

- [4.4.2.1. wheel - UI Events （日本語訳）](https://triple-underscore.github.io/uievents-ja.html#event-type-wheel)

> 注記： UA や入力装置によっては、ホイールが回される速度もデルタ値に影響し得る — 高速になる程 高いデルタ値を生産するように。

## スクロール処理

- [12.2. スクロール処理 - CSSOM View Module （日本語訳）](https://triple-underscore.github.io/cssom-view-ja.html#scrolling-events)
- [12.2. Scrolling - CSSOM View Module](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#scrolling-events)

## 検証

手元の環境で検証した限りでは、`scroll` イベントは `wheel` イベント、`keydown` イベントと連動して発火しているように見えます。
キーボードで同じキーを押し続けた場合、`keydown` イベントも連続して発火するのが一般的なWebブラウザの動作のようですが、**keydown イベントの発火回数はキーを押し続けた時間に比例します**。
`wheel` イベントも同じなのでしょう。

- [PageDown] キーを1回押下 -> `keydown`, `scroll` イベントが1回発火する
- [↓] キーを押し続ける -> 「`keydown` -> `scroll`」の順序で同イベントが連続して同じ回数だけ発火する
- マウスホイールで下スクロールし続ける -> 「`wheel` -> `scroll`」の順序で同イベントが連続して同じ回数だけ発火する

```js
'use strict';
addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
  console.log(event.type);
}, false);

addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
  console.log(event.type);
}, false);

addEventListener('wheel', function (event) {
  console.log(event.type);
}, false);
```

```css
body {
 height: 10000px;
 color: black;
 background-color: #eef;
}
```

```html
<p>sample</p>
```

Re: @letrec

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。「高速になる程 高いデルタ値を生産する」分だけ`wheel`イベントは少なくなり、それと連動して`scroll`イベントも減るという解釈でよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: 「高速」がトリガーではないと思います。「短時間でホイールスクロール→ホイールイベントの発火回数が少ない→スクロールイベントの発火回数が少ない」ではないかと推察します。